# Product search engines, and filtering on attributes ala eBay - how is it done?

Tags: search

Apologies in advance if this is a common question...I think I'm having trouble finding answers because I'm not sure what the problem is actually called!

The background to the problem is - if you look at a service like ebay, when you make a query, you can select a category to drill down in you results. And then when you drill down a leaf category, you can start using filters. So if you select televisions, you might get a variety of filters - like panel technology (oled, lcd, crt), screen size (22", 32", 40" etc.), brand (sony, samsung, lg etc.). The different filters show you the number of results each filter will produce.

Key point: as you select filters, the filters available update. So if you select sony and oled, the screensize filter (and the others) will update to match results available within the constraints of the previously chosen filters.

My question is...how would you implement this kind of filter system in a search engine. Or specifically, how would you calculate the number of results available for a give combination of filters? How do you work out and update the 'filter histogram' as the user makes filter choices?

It seems like a complex problem. Does ebay precalculate the number of results for every possible combination of filters under a leaf category?

Or is there some other smarter way of handling this?

I hope my question makes sense :) Thanks for ANY help! :)

Comment: 1) Apply the selected filters to narrow down the products, 2) accumulate the attributes of the filtered products to figure out what else you can still filter by. This is not even necessarily very complex or time consuming depending on the data set.

Comment: If you have a small dataset, that might be reasonable. But what if you have an eBay-sized dataset? Maybe precalculate results for combinations up to a couple of filters long and then calculate on the fly based on the result set if the 'chain of filters' gets longer than that and the result set narrows?